# Не игнорируются файлы добавленные в .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Так как я использую `TypeScript`, мне нет необходимости в js файлах, ВебПаком я выкидываю js'ки (скомпилированные тем же ВебПаком) в другой проект, где они продолжают успешно работать. Но вот `Visual Studio 2015` тоже компилит ts в js. Да ещё и набрасывает файлы с расширением .map, которые мне очень засоряют проект.
Все мои ts'ки и все мои папки находятся в папке "Scripts".

Вот строки из файла ".gitignore":

```
 /Scripts/*.js
 /Scripts/*.map
 /Scripts/*/*.js
 /Scripts/*/*.map
```

Comment: Добавлю к существующему ответу так же то, что файлы уже добавленные в репозиторий, надо оттуда удалить даже если они попадают под гитигнор маску. Иначе гит их все равно будет видеть.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, тут проблема с относительными путями. Пример использования:

```
# игнорировать все файлы в каталоге scripts/
scripts/
# игнорировать scripts/some.js, но не scripts/jquery/some.js
scripts/*.js
# игнорировать все .js файлы в каталоге scripts/
scripts/**/*.js
```

Сам файл `.gitignore`, соответственно, должен лежать в корне.

Больше информации по ссылке: [Игнорирование файлов](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)